# Refractive index in air depending on altitude

Tags: optics, refraction, air

For a homework I need to find, in the case of a mirage, why we can model the refractive index as $n(z)=n_0\sqrt{1+kz}$ (k is constant, z is altitude). I found some demonstrations of the mirage phenomenon but always the first step was to assume this formula.

The mirage phenomenon is based on temperature changes (which implies pressure changes) ... Temperature changes are described depending on altitude by the thermal gradient. These are the main axes of my researches.

I firstly think about Gladstone's Law $n - 1 = K\rho$ (where K is a constant and $\rho$ the air density), but I had some issues with it : firstly, there isn't square root, or square ... Secondly, there isn't $n_0$ ...

I found the formula of the variation of air density by altitude, assuming a linear thermal gradient : $\rho(z)=\rho(z_0)(1-\frac{a(z-z_0)}{T(z_0)})^{\frac{Mg}{Ra}-1}$. But this formula seems hard to use, because of its exponent ...

So, do you know formulas and laws that can help me ?